# Using sam stevens totp - can't get it to work

Tags: java, token, qr-code, totp, google-2fa

I found a project on GitHub to generate and check tokens (TOTP). I tried to get it working but failed. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import dev.samstevens.totp.code.CodeGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.code.CodeVerifier;
import dev.samstevens.totp.code.DefaultCodeGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.code.DefaultCodeVerifier;
import dev.samstevens.totp.code.HashingAlgorithm;
import dev.samstevens.totp.exceptions.CodeGenerationException;
import dev.samstevens.totp.exceptions.QrGenerationException;
import dev.samstevens.totp.qr.QrData;
import dev.samstevens.totp.qr.QrGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.qr.ZxingPngQrGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.secret.DefaultSecretGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.secret.SecretGenerator;
import dev.samstevens.totp.time.SystemTimeProvider;
import dev.samstevens.totp.time.TimeProvider;
import dev.samstevens.totp.recovery.RecoveryCodeGenerator;

import static dev.samstevens.totp.util.Utils.getDataUriForImage;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TwoFactorAuthentication
 */
public class TwoFactorAuthentication extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public TwoFactorAuthentication() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        
        
        //SecretGenerator secretGenerator = new DefaultSecretGenerator();
        //String secret = secretGenerator.generate();
        String secret = "XAFXRG3TNMLHENVAQTD5ZJOTC2MHTIVE";
        
        QrData data = new QrData.Builder()
                   .label("dummyuser@dummy.com")
                   .secret(secret)
                   .issuer("PORTAL")
                   .algorithm(HashingAlgorithm.SHA256) // More on this below
                   .digits(6)
                   .period(60)
                   .build();
        
        String code = request.getQueryString().replace("code=", "");
        response.getWriter().append("\r\nCode: " + code);//.append(request.getContextPath());
        
        TimeProvider timeProvider = new SystemTimeProvider();
        CodeGenerator codeGenerator = new DefaultCodeGenerator(HashingAlgorithm.SHA256);
        DefaultCodeVerifier verifier = new DefaultCodeVerifier(codeGenerator, timeProvider);
        verifier.setTimePeriod(60);
        verifier.setAllowedTimePeriodDiscrepancy(2);

        // secret = the shared secret for the user
        // code = the code submitted by the user
        boolean successful = verifier.isValidCode(secret, code);
        if (successful) System.out.println(successful);
        response.getWriter().append("\r\nResult: " + successful);//.append(request.getContextPath());
        
        try {
            QrGenerator generator = new ZxingPngQrGenerator();
            byte[] imageData = generator.generate(data);
            String mimeType = generator.getImageMimeType();
            String dataUri = getDataUriForImage(imageData, mimeType);
            response.getWriter().append("\r\ndataUri: " + dataUri);//.append(request.getContextPath());
        } catch (QrGenerationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

I generated the QR code using the project as you can see above, and scanned it to an authenticator app to generate tokens for me. Whatever code I give the form, the authenticator app fails. Can anyone explain to me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: any luck on this as i am facing same issue

Comment: I did found a solution but I don't work at that place anymore. I will try to solve it again and post it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with Google Authenticator app recently. It turns out, some authenticator apps silently ignore the `period` and `digits` parameters from the URI. In case of Google Authenticator, it simply defaults to `30` and `6`, respectively.

This causes code verification to fail, as the app generating the code and the verifying utility work with different parameters.

Comment: I tried different params on both ends including the 30 and 6.
None of that work.

Comment: I ended up using two projects, one to generate the QR code and one to generate a token to send by email or verify an entered token.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that the `codeVerifier.isValidCode` method receives the secret as the first parameter and the otp code as the second parameter, in my case it was doing the inverse.

My code:

```
public UserDto validateOtp(Long userId, LoginDto loginDto) {
        var user = findUserIfExists(userId);
        var isValidOtp = codeVerifier.isValidCode(user.getSecret2FA(),loginDto.getOtp().toString());
        if (!isValidOtp) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Invalid Otp");
        }

        return converterObject(user, UserDto.class);
    }
```